# Showing values that are larger than fixed axis in excel

Tags: excel

I want to fix my Y-axis to 10, but have a data point with y value of 25 and would like it to be shown in my chart as pushed up against the upper limit of the y-axis.

Is this possible without macros etc? Currently that data point just dissapears from view.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the Y-axis with right mouse button. Choose format and there you can set the maximum. If you have higher value than the maximum, it doesn't matter.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yea I got the Y-Axis set to the maximum I want, but I would like higher than max value to still appear, they will just be set at the max.For example Y-Axis max is 10, but a data point has y value of 15 I want that to show up at the max of 10